# Minecraft Repeater: Possible to change tick of repeater via redstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am working on a piston-door design that looks like this:[image: Before Redstone]

and this is what it looks like after: [image: After Redstone Activated]

Now, the issue I am having is retraction. I figured if I can change the tick of the right piston, this issue will be resolved. So my question is: Is it possible to change the tick rate of the repeater without me doing it?

Comment: I recommend you post another question with more details about what you are trying to accomplish as well as an explanation of the circuit you have already tried and the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.  You can not change the [repeater delay](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater#Signal_delay) using redstone.

You could accomplish this using command blocks.  I recommend redesigning the circuit so that this is not needed.

Comment: Very compact way of saying everything that can be said about this case. Well done!